# Exception on backpress fragment ..Searched but doesn't found any such

Tags: android, exception, android-fragments

-I am having problem in fragment.. when i press back button or home button app crashes.. i search Google n stack overflow    , but not applicable to mine.. can anyone suggest

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(2285): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(2285): Process: com.iaboh, PID: 2285
 E/AndroidRuntime(2285): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
 E/AndroidRuntime(2285):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
```

Comment: We can't help you without any code.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling `startActivity` using any activity context. You have two solutions.

**Solution 1**

Use activity context while calling `startActivity()`

**Solution 2**

Add this to your intent. Only if you want to launch an activity form a non activity context. Be careful with this flag. As per android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

*When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started; instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the screen with the state it was last in.*

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: Nice one, and will be more nice if link of documentation added in the word. I'm sorry i didn't see your answer when I was writing.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna: Appreciate your suggestion. Added the link.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly saying to add [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), Please consider the error.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call first

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

That means all previous activity are clear 
Then call the new activity

```
startActivity(intent)
```